# Get changed values before committing SQLAlchemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy model instance with new values pending a `commit()` to write them to the database.  How can I check the old values that are in the database without issuing a `rollback()`?

Answer (score 11):

You can get the history of every SQLAlchemy mapped attribute using the inspection api.  See [the docs on `History`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.History) for what information is available.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

old = {}

for attr in sa.inspect(item).attrs:
    if attr.history.has_changes():
        old[attr.key] = attr.history.deleted
```